# How to retrieve usage metrics for Dialogflow via an API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

There is no information in the Dialogflow docs. There is no mention of Dialogflow on the GCP metrics page here https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp. I can view usage metrics at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/dialogflow.googleapis.com/metrics?project={PROJECT-NAME}

What am I missing here?!?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this gives you the metrics you want, but this page: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/history describes how to view these logs in Stackdriver, which does have an API to be able to retrieve chunks of your GCP logging. You'll need to do some filtering (I haven't played a lot with the Stackdriver API, but I'm sure there are filter methods on there) but it should be able to give you the Dialogflow logs, which from there you can build some metrics from that?

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't realise that I hadn't flipped that switch in the agent settings to log usage to Google Cloud. Now I need to figure out the api!